# Level Instance Blueprint Option Hidden UE5

Tags: unreal, unreal-5

So, here’s the deal. I’m trying to make level instance blueprints with Megascan assets (i.e. group them and convert to a single blueprint), but when I select them all and right-click, I can’t find the option to convert the meshes to a level instance blueprint. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? (I’m using a Mac, just so you know.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unreal Engine 5, you should be able to achieve a better result with the merge operation. Navigate to Tools, then select "Merge Actors" to open up the Merge Actors window and perform the action.

[image: Merge Actors]

Comment: Thanks! That worked!